# Cypress: The html report generated does not show the steps but shows random code in the mochawesome report

Tags: cypress, mochawesome

```
"pretest": "rm -r ./cypress/reports/*.html  & rm -r ./cypress/reports/*.json ",
"posttest": "npm run merge-report && npm run generate-fullreport",
"test": "npm run cypress-test || npm run posttest",
"cypress-test": "cypress run --spec ./cypress/e2e/feature_files/dashboard/arrivals.feature --reporter mochawesome",
"merge-report": "mochawesome-merge ./cypress/reports/*.json -o ./cypress/reports/executionReport.json",
"generate-fullreport": "marge ./cypress/reports/executionReport.json --reportDir ./cypress/reports/"
```

After executing all this using 'npm test' command the html report generated shows random code instead of the steps
[html report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1531f.png)